# Jekyll Dependency Error when Upgrading from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Following [the official update guide](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/), I recently upgraded from Jekyll 2.x to Jekyll 3.1.1.

After the installation, running `jekyll serve` produced the following error:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have `jekyll-markdown-block` or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate `jekyll-markdown-block-1.1.0`, because `jekyll-3.1.1` conflicts with `jekyll (~> 2.0)`' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!

So from there I `sudo gem update jekyll-markdown-block`, but the error still persisted. I then tried to update all of my gems:

```
sudo gem update `gem list | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

And then out of desperation, uninstalled *all* of my gems (except the core one, which I was not permitted to uninstall):

```
sudo gem uninstall `gem list | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

I then proceeded to install jekyll like normal (assuming I was now working from a clean slate):

```
sudo gem install jekyll
Fetching: liquid-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed liquid-3.0.6
Fetching: kramdown-1.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed kramdown-1.9.0
....
Parsing documentation for jekyll-watch-1.3.1
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-watch-1.3.1
Parsing documentation for jekyll-3.1.1
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-3.1.1
14 gems installed
```

After then installing `jekyll-press` and `jekyll-markdown-block` (a new error message complained I didn't have them), I then received the original error message complaining about Jekyll 2.x.

How can I fully remove Jekyll 2.x and complete the upgrade without gem dependency errors?

Comment: Have you tried adding `jekyll-markdown-block` to the Gemfile of your jekyll site?

Comment: Try build the site with `bundler`. If you don't have it installed run `gem install bundler` from your command line. Then, add a Gemfile with all gems you need. Then, exec `bundle install`, when bundler will install all required gems and their dependencies. And finally, run `bundle exec  jekyll serve` to serving locally. You can add the flags `--watch` , `--baseurl "" ` and also `--safe` to the `bundle exec` command.

Comment: Update: I ultimately got this to work by going to a new directory and running `jekyll init`. Serving this newly created site worked and I just ported over the old site. I'm pretty sure there were configuration changes that caused the old site to break.

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same problem after updating to jekylls 3.1.2 from 2.x. 
Running `jekyll serve`, I received the following message:

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have kramdown or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently
>   configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message
>   from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- kramdown' If you run into
>   trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!

I did what Virtua Creative suggest on his comment:

```
bundle install
```

and then:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

The initial command was giving me the same error, but the bundle exec works.

Comment: huh, I'm dealing with your same `kramdown` issue, and your solution works, but why?

Comment: I had the same experience. My guess is that `bundle exec jekyll serve` uses the dependencies installed locally by `bundle install`, where as `jekyll serve` uses globally installed gems. I bet if we try `gem install kramdown` or something, it would fix it.

Comment: I ran into this too.  The issue seems to be caused by bundler.  Ran `jekyll serve --trace` and found the exception was throwing in bundler.  When I uninstall bundler, I was able to build the site with jekyll 3.1.2.

Answer (score 6):

Seems that the bundle envitorment is confused. Try `bundle clean --force` - with sudo, if you have permission issues.

Comment: I had 3 versions of kramdown installed. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have installed the bundler,

```
sudo gem install bundler
```